# How to run a program and get its PID in the background

Tags: linux, bash, java, minecraft

I have a Minecraft server startup script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
exec java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

How do I get java process's PID while being able to enter input into the Java process?

if I change the exec line to

```
exec java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar minecraft_server.jar & echo $! > pid
```

it won't let me input any text into the Minecraft server java process.

Comment: Have you tried backgrounding the process, grabbing the PID, and then bringing the process back into the foreground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you start the java process with exec, its PID will be the same as the one of the shell script. So you can do

```
echo $$ > pid
exec java ...
```

Comment: Do you still need to communicate with the server process?

Comment: Yes, I need to communicate with the server process (I use `screen -x mc-vanilla -X stuff "say doing something blah blahboaweohv $(printf '\r')"` to input things into my minecraft server.

Comment: Finally, I've been wondering how to run in foreground and export PID for ages!

Answer (score 0):

`exec` will replace the current process, so running from bash replaces bash, that's why you lose the interactive shell. After starting minecraft, doing `ps aux | grep minecraft_server.jar` will return the process information. If you need it to return just the process id to redirect to a pid file or use in a bash function you can do this: `ps aux | grep minecraft_server.jar | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: The reason I didn't want to do that was because I have multiple minecraft servers running at the same time. I wanted to get the PID of the process so I could kill that process and not the other minecraft servers.

Comment: Gotcha. We use a lot of Tomcat servers at my work and use the ps aux method but use grep to parse the full path of the jar file to differentiate between server instances.